# Most appropriate database structure to store dichotomous keys?

Tags: data-structures, graph

In biology, a dichotomous key ([see example](https://d3n817fwly711g.cloudfront.net/uploads/2019/11/Dichotomous-Key-for-Animals-1024x768.png)) is a flowchart of yes/no decisions that help you identify a species. Like "Does it have fur? yes/no" --> "Does it have feathers? yes/no".

Right now, I have a bunch of them in simple rows in a database, but there is no relationship between each key and its parents; it's just a flat list of rows and all the yes/no logic is handled in code.

It feels like there should be some way to store this kind of related information in a "graph" of some sorts, but I'm not sure of the best approach.

I know how to use relational databases, but have minimal experience with GraphQL. Am I even thinking on the right path..? What's the best way to store things like this (essentially taxonomic trees with mutually exclusive siblings) in a sane data store, preferably so that an algorithm would be able to generate a tree by looking at the data?

Comment: NetworkX could be useful for your purpose , if you have not used it already and willing to consider python for your purpose http://networkx.github.io/   The documentation could be found here https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/index.html

Comment: As for your storage enquiry , please refer this stackflow thread about NetworkX storage https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542058/networkx-storage-of-graph-info

Answer (score 1):

Any graph database would work well for your needs.

I would generally not recommend storing these in a relational database unless you want to use some of the NoSQL features of the database (IE: JSONB in PostgresSQL). Even in that case, I would probably recommend limiting how deep nesting you do on each record.

If you have relatively low nesting, you can probably get away with it. But keep in mind, every level deep is another database query you need to perform. There are performance things you can do, but its typically not worth it.

Though really, you probably could storing this a hash or something, unless it has a lot of records (like a key has 500 options). I wouldn't store them as separate rows. I would just serialize the data, then serialize it to convert it to something you can use. Really not searchable, if you need searchable look at Bo SQL database structures).

Database table now looks like this (JSON serialized, I think, pretty format for easier reading):

```
Name | Dichotomous Keys
Vertebrate | {
 "Does it have Fur": {"yes": "Mammal", "no": "Does it have feathers?"},
 "Does it have Feathers": {"yes": "Bird", "no": "Does it have dry skin?"},
 "Does it ..." {"yes": "...", "no": "..."},
 ...
}

Then use a bit of logic to dig into it. You could compact the hash more, but probably not worth it. The above may be a ram issue, but you could also consider the hash as a form of data cache, as long as you are storing a few KB or so and not MB of data in a field, you should be fine.
``

Note:

GraphQL is definitely not what you are looking for, that's for building APIs. The graph part comes from being able to request data in the form of a graph that explains exactly what data you want rather than a "Here is what you data get take it or leave it" most APIs will give you. Example, though this is a definitely not a valid GraphQL request, but it's similar enough (actual ones are a little bit more "wordy"): `Fetch user(id=100): { [:id, :email, :phone] }` then the GraphQL server would respond with `{ user: { id: 100, email: something@something.com, phone: 123-456-7890} }` instead of the massive amount of data the an API *might* need to send about a user.
```